# (BigTable Query, java API) how to use scan and rowKey at the same time?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

This is how bigTable look like

```
rowKey              column family
            qualifier1  qualifier2   qualifier3
 key1       value1       value2        value3
 key2       value4       value5        value6
 key3       value7       value8        value9
```

if i want to get key1's first 2 qualifiers' value (value1 and value 2) and key2's first 2 qualifiers' value (value4 and value 5)
how can i do it by using java API
tried **BigtableExtendedScan** but i cannot pass 2 rowkeys to this object....
please help here.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solution is use '[readRows()](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-native-java-hello#scanning-all-rows)' method to scan multiple rows in your BigTable instance. You can create Query with rows range from 'START KEY' to 'END KEY':

```
Query query = Query.create(tableId)
          .range("[START KEY]", "[END KEY]")
          .filter(FILTERS.qualifier().regex("[COLUMN PREFIX].*"));
```